# Relacionar dos tablas sql

Tags: sql

Tengo estas dos tablas

**Tabla usuarios**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla publicaciones**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla comentarios**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener todas las publicaciones (de un usuario) junto a su numero de comentarios.

**Tengo esta consulta**

```
SELECT publicaciones.*, count(comentarios.id) AS "comentarios"
FROM publicaciones
LEFT JOIN comentarios
ON revels.id = comentarios.publicacionid
WHERE (publicaciones.userid = 4);
```

El problema es que solo devuelve un resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deberian salir 3 resultados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: cuántos resultados estás esperando?, el usuario que muestras tiene solo una publicación

Comment: Espero 3 resultados

Comment: Si esperas 3, para que haces count?

Comment: algo falta en tu consulta....cuál es la tabla `revels`?

Comment: revels es una vista con todos los comentarios(distintos)?porque no están asociados a ninguna publicación ni nada

Comment: pero no está en el código que pusiste, así que cómo es que ese código está funcionando?. Por favor pon el código exacto que estás usando

Comment: me equivque del nombre, es otra de prueba, ya está actualizado

Answer (score 0):

Te podría recomendar una consulta multitabla como la siguiente

```
SELECT *, U.id AS user_id
P.id AS publicacion_id,
P.texto, 
C.fecha AS fechaComentario,
C.id as comentario_id,
FROM usuarios U,
publicaciones P,
comentarios C
where
P.user_id = U.id ADN 
P.id = C.publicacionesid
```

a texto no le puse alias por que no hay otra cosa que se llame texto y pueda confundir, como si pasa con los ids y las fechas

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: pero esta consulta no cuenta los comentarios como se solicitó. Por otro lado, son inner joins (implícitos), o sea, si no tiene comentarios, la publicación no va a aparecer

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener todos los comentarios asociados a una publicación ,junto con la cantidad de comentarios hechas por el usuario del comentario necesitamos hacer una **subselect**, tal cual:

```
    SELECT publicaciones.*,comentarios.texto as comentario,

(select count(comentarios.id)  from comentarios
 where publicaciones.id = comentarios.publicacionid and
  publicaciones.userid = comentarios.userid) AS "comentarios"

    FROM publicaciones
    LEFT JOIN comentarios
    ON publicaciones.id = comentarios.publicacionid
    WHERE (publicaciones.userid = 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dado que es probable que haya publicaciones que no tienen comentarios, se debe tener cuidado de incluir a esta tabla con un left o right join. Finalmente, agrupar por el id de la publicación, para asegurarse que salga un solo registro por cada una. Esta agrupación puede tener otros campos

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT   usuarios.usuario
       , publicaciones.id
       , publicaciones.texto
       , count(comentarios.id) AS "comentarios"
  FROM publicaciones
       inner join usuarios on publicaciones.userid = usuarios.id
       left join comentarios on comentarios.publicacionid = publicaciones.id
 WHERE publicaciones.userid = 4
 group by usuarios.usuario
        , publicaciones.id
        , publicaciones.texto
;
```

Si esto no diera resultado (ya ves, mysql no es el más estándar y no tengo forma de probarlo ahora), puedes también tirar de una sub-consulta para obtener el número de comentarios, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT   usuarios.usuario
       , publicaciones.id
       , publicaciones.texto
       , (select count(comentarios.id) 
            from comentarios 
           where comentarios.publicacionid = publicaciones.id
         ) AS "comentarios"
  FROM publicaciones
       inner join usuarios on publicaciones.userid = usuarios.id
 WHERE publicaciones.userid = 4
;
```

Como puedes observar, en este caso ya no hace falta agrupar, pues de entrada tienes un solo registro por cada publicación.